# Global inbox/supercollider on mobile should have a way to read more than four entries

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, global-inbox

On a desktop computer the notifications pane in the supercollider has a scrollbar, so I can see all of my messages/notifications by scrolling.  On my (Android) phone, however, I can see the most-recent four entries but nothing past that -- no scrollbar, no "more" link, nothing.  Further, visiting the inbox clears all the notifications, so they won't show up as new next time I'm on a computer where I could see them -- I have to remember to back-read.  I've had to train myself to not click at all if the number in the red bubble is greater than 4, which is pretty annoying (especially as a moderator).

Could we please have some affordance for seeing all the notifications on the phone?  Failing that, could the mobile interface at least not mark as read notifications that were never displayed, so I'll catch them later?

Comment: It's dependent upon the size of the screen AFAIK. On my nexus 7, it shows more than 10 entries. The obvious answer here is to make the list scrollable, but you can always use the desktop version of the site on your phone.

Comment: That makes sense.  I can't make my phone's screen bigger, so I hope they can provide some affordance.  The desktop version of the site is way too wide to work on my phone at a size I could actually read.

Comment: You can also bookmark this page: http://stackexchange.com/users/505925/monica-cellio?tab=inbox to go directly to your SE inbox. Not sure what that looks like on the mobile theme, though.