# How to see the Stack Exchange notifications on separate page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

Usually Stack Overflow provides the mechanism of seeing notifications on the left corner of the page, probably using JQuery/AJAX. But for slow internet connections, this is really exhausting. Is there any mechanism to see notifications on a separate page?

It would for example be great to see the notifications on separate pages such as `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/notifications` etc.

Comment: Agreed, both the notification and "my logins" popups do not work by default.  I had to add an exception to my ad blocker.  But in many corporate workplaces, adding exceptions is not an option.

Comment: If you want it as raw JSON then you have [inbox items](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine) and [notifications](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/notices/genuwine). :)

Comment: @Sha Wiz: I was just asking for easier way, not much complicated! :)

Answer (score 5):

On your profile there is a responses tab. This tab lists all replies, answers, etc you get.

[image]

The only thing it doesn't show are badges earned, but you can see those under Activity -> All

[image]

You can also set email notifications up from the inbox.

[image]

Comment: Exactly! But little different. For slow internet connection, to go to the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220830/veekay?tab=responses page, it's really time consuming and exhausting (we need to remember user name, some digits also!). So, I am wondering if there is the way to provide the mechanism so that notifications can be directly viewed as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/notifications.

Comment: But waiting for an email doesn't really work with comments. I don't think people like waiting for a reply. (Think this: Person A posts comment. Newbie OP replies after 5 minute. Person A doesn't get notified until they receive the email. OP gets upset. Newbie OP says SO sucks. OP quits using site). Yes that's kind of an extreme, but it has happened before.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Well personally, I think that's their problem. They can't always expect instant replies from people... But this *is* sort of an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can get to your global (not per-site) **inbox** through your network profile page: https://stackexchange.com/users/your-number/your-name?tab=inbox.  I bookmarked this page on my phone so I could see inbox messages without clearing the counter, because of [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173087/162102).

If you just want the inbox for a particular site, you could bookmark that page instead.

This doesn't help with **notifications** (edits to your posts, badges, etc).  You said notifications but implied in comments that you're concerned about the inbox, e.g. comments.

Comment: Oh that's great! I totally forgot about the network wide profiles..